# Error: In adding Firebase Storage dependency to Android Studio Project?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I have created a Firestore Project in Android Studio. In which I have Firebase Authorization implemented and that is working absolutely fine. I am able to push documents to Firestore Database.

But now, I am trying to add functionality using which I can store media/images to Firebase Storage but when I am adding this dependency to app's build.gradle file, I am getting this error:

Dependency added:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
```

This is the error that I am getting:

```
Could not find firebase-common.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.0).
Searched in the following locations:https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-common/16.0.0/firebase-common-16.0.0.jar
```

FYI, In my project I already have this kind of configuration:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
```

And

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I can not find what is going wrong when I just add firebase-storage dependency to my Android project.

Here is my app level build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.firebase.example"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Here is my module level build.gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1' // google-services plugin
        classpath 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work guys. You can simply compare my new gradle files. The issue was conflicting google services libraries and gradle version. So, I created new project and just added dependencies again like this and it worked.

**So, I removed this from app/build.gradle:**

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
```

**And, removed this from module/build.gradle:**

```
classpath 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1'
```

**and updated gradle version in module/build.gradle:**

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

New build.gradle files look like this.

**module/build.gradle:**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1' // google-services plugin

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**app/build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "master.firebasesetup"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added these to your root level gradle file?

```
buildscript {

    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1' 
    }
}

allprojects {

    repositories {

        google() 
    }
}
```

Comment: Bijal, thank. That was already there but still I was getting errors.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `dependencies {classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'}` and `repositories { google()}` on your root level build.gradle file. Have you added that? And further more please provide your whole build.gradle file in order to understand your problem .

Comment: Great what version you are using for auth?

Comment: implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0'

Comment: In App gradle `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'` and in Root gradle `classpath 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'`
This worked well for me it successfully generated build

Comment: Adding firebase-storage to exactly this configuration gives me error: Failed to resolve: firebase-common

Comment: The difference between your app gradle and mine is the `targetSdkVersion:27` and `compileSdkVersion 27` and on the root level `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-beta01'`
Check if this can make a difference

Comment: Tried this but getting other error like: Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.6. Current version is 4.4.

Comment: Update gradle version

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade the following:

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:16.0.0'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0'
```

into this:

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.2'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
```

Check here for more info:

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

Comment: Peter, I tried this and still I am getting error while building project.

Comment: Failed to resolve: firebase-database-collection
Failed to resolve: protolite-well-known-types

Comment: add `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'`

Comment: add the above dependency, then clean and rebuild

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use firebase assitant set up

[image]