# Failed to resolve play-services-auth and firebase-core

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Project sync failed with the following errors.

```
Failed to resolve: play-services-auth
Open File


Failed to resolve: firebase-core
Open File
```

Tried replacing `google()` with `maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }` but no luck. Here is the content of build.gradle files.

build.gradle (app)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        //google()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin' version '0.7.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
//apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    //other codes
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    //other codes

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

build.gradle(project)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

ext {

    minSdkVersion = 16
    targetSdkVersion = 27
    compileSdkVersion = 27

    //Other code
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

If I put `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` just below `apply plugin: 'io.fabric'` I get the following errors

`Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-license:11.6.0.
Searched in the following locations:
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth-license/11.6.0/play-services-auth-license-11.6.0.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth-license/11.6.0/play-services-auth-license-11.6.0.aar
    https://jitpack.io/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth-license/11.6.0/play-services-auth-license-11.6.0.pom
    https://jitpack.io/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth-license/11.6.0/play-services-auth-license-11.6.0.aar
    https://maven.google.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth-license/11.6.0/play-services-auth-license-11.6.0.pom
    https://maven.google.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth-license/11.6.0/play-services-auth-license-11.6.0.aar
    https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth-license/11.6.0/play-services-auth-license-11.6.0.pom
    https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth-license/11.6.0/play-services-auth-license-11.6.0.aar
    https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth-license/11.6.0/play-services-auth-license-11.6.0.pom
    https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth-license/11.6.0/play-services-auth-license-11.6.0.aar
Required by:
    project :app > com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.2`

Comment: Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51119235/9734616

Comment: Check your proxy settings. If you are behind corporate network, you may need to set credentials.

Comment: Thanks but I am not running behind proxy. I also tried from Bluetooth tethering from my mobile.

Answer (score 1):

Did you generate the google-services.json file from the firebase under the project>app and add all the plugins at the bottom

Comment: google-services.json has already been included. Sorry, what do you mean by "add all the plugins at the bottom"?

Comment: apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
These lines should be at bottom

Answer (score 0):

In your build.gradle where you reference  'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.+'

Please use 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.23.0'

instead of 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.+'